# Rewrite logical expression using only implications

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How would you rewrite logical expression (see example) using only implications and negation?

Example:
 (A and !B) or (!C and D)

I know that A->B is equivalent to !(!(A->B)) = !(A and !B) = !A or B, but how would you rewrite or?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You apparently know that $A \rightarrow B \Leftrightarrow \neg A \lor B$ for any formulas $A$ and $B$

Well, from that, it immediately follows that $\neg A \rightarrow B \Leftrightarrow \neg \neg A \lor B \Leftrightarrow A \lor B$

So now you know how to rewrite any $\lor$ using $\neg$ and $\rightarrow$, and by Demorgan that tells you how to rewrite any $\land$ using $\neg$ and $\rightarrow$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

$A \to B$ is equiv to $\lnot A \lor B$ and $A \land B$ is equiv to $\lnot (A \to \lnot B)$.

Thus, for $(A \land \lnot B) \lor (\lnot C \land D)$ we can first remove the two "and", to get:

> $\lnot (A \to B) \lor \lnot (\lnot C \to \lnot D)$.

Finally, we can remove "or":

> > $(A \to B) \to \lnot (\lnot C \to \lnot D)$.

Comment: So the example I provided would be: (A->B)->!(C->!D) ?

Comment: @Marinaro - quite right ...